# Packing Fraction vs. Packing Density

Tags: density

Hello: I am confused if Packing fraction and packing density mean the same thing. I have been led to believe they are different. I would like help in sorting the confusion. Thanks.

Also is packing density and density the same or different.

Comment: Can you give some details, please? What is being packed? I have never heard of any of these terms. In what context to they appear?

Comment: As a materials chemist I admittedly use these interchangeably but yes they are different! Packing fraction is the space filled per unit cell. Different crystal structures have different packing arrangements and 3D frameworks so naturally you are going to get some that really pack tight (e.g. close packed) and others that are a little less filled (e.g. body centred). So you could say the packing fraction was 0.74 for instance. Packing density refers to the mass per unit cell. So if you knew you had a certain number of oxygen atoms and a certain number of aluminium atoms say

Comment: (cont) you could work out the mass per unit cell, which to my understanding is the packing density. Whether the local unit cell density is the same as the total crystal density depends on macroscopic properties such as grains, defects impurities etc etc...

Comment: ^ That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are and aren't the same thing, because you may, in some cases, use them interchangeably. Other times, as AngusTheMan, you may not. Wikipedia says though that: "A packing density or packing fraction of a packing in some space is the fraction of the space filled by the figures making up the packing." Signifying they are the same thing(when they aren't).

Packing Density and Density are the same thing:

Density=Mass/Volume
Packing Density=Mass/Unit Cell

The Unit Cell may be used as a unit of volume, just like a cubic foot may be used as a unit of volume, if you know the volume of the unit cell.

UCDavis: "A unit cell is the most basic and least **volume consuming** repeating structure of any solid. It is used to visually simplify the crystalline patterns solids arrange themselves in. When the unit cell repeats itself, the network is called a lattice."

Answer (score -1):

Both terms mean the same and express how much a given volume is filled by a material (or object) compared to the total volume. The total volume is the sum of the volume of the material and the volume that is not filled by the material. The packing density is often abbreviated by the letter Phi and following ratio:

$\phi=\frac{\text{occupied volume}}{\text{total volume}}$.

It follows that $0\le\phi\le1$.

Instead of volume also the areas or masses can be compared. Then one speaks about the area density or mass density.
Confusing might be only that people use different number representations. One can normalize to 1 or normalize to 100%, i.e. 0.3 or 30% mean the same.
Another confusion is by porosity that not measures the occupied space but the non-occupied space. It is just 1-packing density, or 100%-packing density (in case of percentage).